# Why i am getting a runtime error which says variable length array bound evaluates to non-positive value 0?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, dynamic-programming

Longest Palindromic substring
I am getting a runtime error which says variable length array bound evaluates to non-positive value 0. Why am i getting this error?

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
    int n = s.size();
    string res;
    bool dp[n][n];
    //2d dp table 
    //dp[i] = whether the substring from index i to j is a palindrome or not
    memset(dp, false, sizeof(dp));
    int x,y, max = INT_MIN;
    
    if(n==0||n==1) return s;
    
    for(int i = n-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=i;j<=n-1;j++){
            if(i==j)//every single character is palindrome
                dp[i][j] = true;
            else if(s[i] ==s[j]){//More than one characters
                if(j-i==1)//2 characters
                    dp[i][j] = true;
                else // more than two characters
                dp[i][j] = dp[i+1][j-1];
            }
        if (dp[i][j] && j-1>= max){
            max = j-i;
            x = i;
            y =j;
        }
    }
}
    res = s.substr(x,y);
    return res;
}
};
```

Comment: First, variable length arrays are non-standard in C++, and not supported by many compilers.

Comment: Because `s` is an empty string? [Edit] the question to include the code where you call `longestPalindrome` and a [mre] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You want a `std::vector`. VLAs are *not* a feature of standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we try to give the size of the array as negative.
Consider:

```
n=2
m=-3

int a[n][m] // error.
```

Now if I create an array with this negative sized m, then this error will occur.